# Должная судьба ответа в случае полной или частичной потери актуальности

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

Речь об этом [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535153/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и пока единственном на него ответе.

Вопрос в первоначальном состоянии не имел конкретизации, что по определению из-за преследуемой в нём тематики лишало возможности дать какой-либо вразумительный ответ. Тем не менее, ответ, пусть и с возможным перегибом в сторону несерьёзности, предоставлен был и следовал цели в максимально ясной форме объяснить вопрошающему суть проблемы с написанием ответа на его вопрос. Можно было бы обойтись и просто комментарием, но там их и так уже было две штуки, подразумевавших тоже самое.

Автор вопроса прекрасно понял посыл, следствием чего явилась соответствующая правка текста вопроса.

Следует ли теперь удалить корректирующий ответ в виду того, что с историей вопроса и его правок вновь читающие вряд ли станут разбираться, а потому он может показаться (в виду минуса, кому-то уже показался), мягко говоря, не вполне адекватным, ибо теперь конкретизация в вопросе имеется, а ответ уповает на её отсутствие?

---

**Дополнение**

Оба ответа, в целом, предложили одинаковую реакцию - публикация соответствующего предупреждения в проблемном вопросе. Но второй ответ оказался развёрнуто аргументирован, а потому именно он был отмечен принятым. Спасибо.

Comment: Конкретно этот ответ я бы оставил за отличный слог)

Comment: @Утка , благодарю за комплимент

Answer (score 10, accepted):

На мой взгляд, **вопрос подлежит закрытию**. И соответственно, **отвечать на него не стоило**.

Там со вчерашнего дня висит моя закрывашка по "Необходимо конкретизировать вопрос", которая по неизвестным мне причинам не получила поддержки сообщества. Я допускаю, что сообщество может быть со мной не согласно, но своё мнение, тем не менее, изложу.

---

И вы сами же попали в ситуацию, объясняющую, почему такие вопросы принято закрывать: вопрос *слишком неконкретен* и потому к нему **крайне высок риск оставить ответ, который не решит проблему**. Потому что не выходя за формат/объём типичных ответов StackExchange в хороший ответ на подобный вопрос влезет либо:

- "Общий обзор", который содержит только общие направления в сторону решения.
  ...что не решит конкретной проблемы, с которой столкнулся ТС, из-за **общности**.
- "Краткое описание для человека **в теме**", что ТС не поймёт, так как, цитирую:

  > Буду признателен, если приведете код к ответу.

  ...это явный сигнал того, что человек в области **ориентируется плохо**.

---

#### Не стоит оставлять ответы на плохие вопросы.

...потому что это удивительно часто кончается... чем-то таким.

Сейчас в ответе можно оставить отметку, что он **устарел**, т. е. относится не к последней ревизии вопроса. Удалять жалко, он интересный.

Comment: Вы безусловно правы. Но лично мне понятны причины, по которым вопрос не подвергся обычной практике закрытия из-за того, что он недостаточно конкретизирован. Вопрос относится к той теме, которую многие участники могли бы назвать интересной, плюс - общая редкость появления вопросов по этой теме вообще. Лично у меня рука не поднимается рубить с плеча, а хочется как-то намекнуть автору на необходимость приведения вопроса в надлежащее соответствие. И вроде получилось, вопрос теперь вполне пригоден для ответа. Другое дело, конечно, что надо было опираться исключительно на комментарии.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, для сохранения "историчности", ответ следует оставить, влепив в его начало огромный дисклеймер.