# Является ли ссылка на книгу ответом?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы, ответ-ссылка

Не хотелось бы привлекать внимание к собственной персоне, но - получил вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558626/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA) тряпкой :), что ответ на конкретный вопрос о существовании алгоритма в виде указания на этот алгоритм в "Искусстве программирования" ответом не является. Хотелось бы понять, это действительно так, или нет. Ну, чтоб не попадать больше впросак. Может, я и в самом деле чего-то недопонимаю в правилах?.. Вроде бы было в правилах, что нежелательно давать URL - из-за того, что может поменяться. Но книга - это же, так сказать, разумное, доброе, вечное? Она же поменяться не может?

Или ответ - только перенабор нескольких страниц с формулами?...

Comment: Если для ответа действительно требуется набрать несколько страниц текста, то это плохой вопрос (причина закрытия "необходимо конкретизировать вопрос": "В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ").

Comment: мне кажется что в ответе необходимо привести краткую выжимку из материала на который Вы ссылаетесь в ином случае *такому* ответу место в комментарии. IMHO

Answer (score 9):

В вашем случае **ссылка лишь дополняет ответ**. На вопрос **"существует ли"** вы дали однозначный ответ **"да"**. Так что *формально* это вполне себе ответ `:)`

Другое дело, что вопрос требует уточнения, автора интересует явно не только это. Потому вопрос и был закрыт. **Отвечать на вопросы, которым грозит закрытие, обычно не стоит*.**

---

Является ли ссылка на книгу ответом? **Нет** (в общем случае). По той же причине, что и обычная: в теле ответа непосредственно решение отсутствует. Если книги Кнута, допустим, человечество ещё долгое время будет держать на виду, другим книгам может повезти меньше.

Ответом на вопрос "как найти все топологические сортировки" мог быть алгоритм, изложенный псевдокодом или на любом известном языке, например. Без формул, оценки сложности и без доказательства корректности (хотя они могли бы сделать ответ лучше). По псевдокоду легко реконструировать решение, никуда дополнительно не залезая.

---

* *См. также [обсуждение другого случая ответа на вопрос, которому грозило закрытие](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3212/181100).*

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я понял идея и дух сообщества, получить исчерпывающий ответ на свой вопрос прямо на сайте. А если для этого нужно проследовать по ссылке или искать и изучать дополнительные материалы, то смысл теряется.

Comment: ссылка в ответе может быть уместна но только как источник или же как более подробное руководство если в ответе краткая выжимка из этого источника

Comment: Если строго следовать такой идее, то   будут отвечать только на примитивные вопросы (в ассимптотическом результате тут просто станет нечего делать).